# Refresh HTML PHP page on submit while running another page?

Tags: php, html, forms

I've got a page which has a load of invoices on it and I want to be able to delete an invoice and then see that it's been deleted.

What I'm using currently is (bastardizing other code as I don't really know HTML / PHP all too well...!)

```
  <form name="form1" action="deleteinvoice.php" method="post">
    <input name="invoiceid" type="number" size="20"/>
    <input id="input" 
        type='submit' 
        value='Delete' 
        onclick="form1.action='deleteinvoice.php';target='my-iframe'" 
        class="button save-big" 
        disabled="disabled" >
    <input type="checkbox" 
        name="agree" 
        value="yes" 
        onclick="input.disabled = !this.checked" />Confirm you have the correct invoice number
    </form>

<iframe name="my-iframe" src="deleteinvoice.php" style="display:none"></iframe>
```

This is working fine in so far as it's deleting the invoice (so I know the deleteinvoice.php page is working) but what I could really do with it also doing is refreshing the page that I was on so that the deleted invoice disappears and the form is blank again.

Thoughts?

Comment: `onclick="blahblah; form1.reset()"`?

Comment: @MarcB would you put that the input with the id of input? i.e. onclick="form1.action='deleteinvoice.php';target='my-iframe';from1.reset()" ?   That would sort the resetting the form side of things, but still not sure about the refreshing the page to show that the invoice has been deleted?

Comment: Is there any particular reason as to why you're using an `iframe`?

Comment: @KevinM1, I'd bet he does it to prevent `deleteinvoice.php`'s output from messing up the page. Sam, you may not know it yet, but you really want to study jQuery and AJAX :-)

Comment: @KevinM1 so it doesn't load out to a new page, thereby losing parameters already posted into this page.  I'm going to give lserni's solution a whirl

Comment: @lserni I've dabbled with jQuery which seems amazing and I know about AJAX but want to get PHP down a bit better first!  Will definitely put it on my list of things to do however

Comment: @sam.clements jQuery's `$.post()` is really all you need.  It allows you to send data via POST to a back end script, and then manipulate the DOM with the response it sends back.  No more needing to use things from the early-to-mid 2000's to do the job!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick and dirty PHP workaround would be to create yet another PHP page that would delete the invoice and reload the page you're in:

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    require 'deleteinvoice.php';
    ob_end_clean();
    Header("Location: the-page-you-were-looking-before.php");
?>
```

Then set the form action to

```
onclick="form1.action='workaroundpage.php';"
```

Note: this is *not* a very clean or secure setup. It's just a simple make-do since you say you're not very conversant with PHP.

What the above code does, is to first load the true "deleteinvoice.php", just as if it was that page. So the invoice gets deleted as before. But any output from that page is first buffered by `ob_start()` and then discarded by `ob_end_clean()`, making this equivalent (client side) to a blank page. It then redirects the browser (it can do so, because it's as if no output was created) to the original page, not in the iframe but in the main window. So you find yourself back at the list page, with the invoice deleted.

A much more elegant (but proportionately more complex) way of doing this could be e.g. through a jQuery AJAX call and invoice DOM element destruction.

Comment: I assume I would need to post any variables across and back again? Or would it know what I had posted previously?

Comment: That's the (limited :-) ) beauty of the thing. If you change the `ACTION`, then the *same* variables that before were sent to `deleteinvoice.php` will now be sent to `workaround.php`. And since `workaround.php` includes `deleteinvoice.php`, this last file will continue receiving the same things it got before, and should therefore work identically. (Unless it checks its main file name, which is a common precaution in many frameworks, but I don't think you're using one).

Comment: That sounds genius - it's an internally hosted site that's not accessible to the outside world, so I'm not toooooo worried about security.

Comment: As long as you're aware of it. Sad but true story: worked for ${BIGFIRM}, set up a "internal site" without much caring about security, then left for greener pastures, and six months later some... "creative guy" decided to publish the site as Employee Area on the Internet. They got exploited six ways to Sunday, and wanted to make it *my* fault [in a way... it was!]. I was young and a fool (*but I changed: now I'm older*), and it taught me **never**, **ever** to forget worrying about security. Or at least to get a disclaimer accepted in writing from the CEO :-)